# Extract specific lines between variable no of. lines from text file in python

Tags: python, regex, search, extract

This question may have been asked before but those does not match my situation. I have already gone through most of them but none of the solutions are helping.

So, here is the problem. I have a text file containing a large no of lines.
Here is a sample of the file:

```
yyyyyy=xxxx  
yyyyyy=xxxxxxxx

Sun Oct 22 15:19:23 PDT 2017  
calling sequenc node

++ entering node aaa (       )  
Sun Oct 22 15:19:23 PDT 2017  
lines xxxxxxxx  
calling wroot.bat  

++ entering node bbb (xxx       )  
Sun Oct 22 15:19:23 PDT 2017  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
calling bsod.bat   
xaaaaa
bbbbb
tttttt
bbb completed successfully  
-- exiting node bbb  

++ entering node ccc (yyyy      )  
Sun Oct 22 15:19:35 PDT 2017  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
calling wpretest.bat
```

Now, I want to extract the lines from the calling part(included) to the lines that is above the completed successfully line. Also I want to extract the line only when it has a beginning with ++. The no of. lines after calling varies. It have may have a blank, 2 or more lines following it. If there is no line following it,I just want to extract the calling line. If there is completed successfully in the next line, then also I want to extract the single calling line. And if there are other lines between the calling line and successfully completed,I want to extract all of them.

Here is the code I have tried along with regular expressions too(which did not seem to work)

```
with open('myfile.txt','r') as log: 
    for line in log:

        match = re.search(node_name_pattern, line)
        if line.startswith('++') and match:           
            node_name.append(match.group())
            nn=match.group()
        match2 = re.search(node_parameter, line)
        if line.startswith('++') and match2:
            parameter.append(match2.group())
            start_time.append(log.next().strip())
            features.append(log.next().strip())
        if "calling" in line :
                content.append(line.strip())
```

Here is the expected output:

```
calling wroot.bat
calling bsod.bat,
xaaaaa,
bbbbb,
tttttt 
calling wpretest.bat
```

Comment: please include the code you have tried and sample text

Comment: Where is your sample? could you give us a detailed example with input and expected output?

Comment: Sorry. Just edited my question.

Comment: Could you add the expected output as well? Thanks

Comment: Added it. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `regex` this should work:

```
r'(?<=\n)calling.*?(?=\n[^\n]*completed succ[^\n]*\n|\n\+\+|\s*\Z)'
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> bla = open('bla').read()
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\n)calling.*?(?=\n[^\n]*completed succ[^\n]*\n|\n\+\+|\s*\Z)',bla,re.DOTALL)
['calling sequenc node\n', 'calling wroot.bat  \n', 'calling bsod.bat   \nxaaaaa\nbbbbb\ntttttt', 'calling wpretest.bat']
```

**Breaking down the regex**

So you can play around with it:

1. `(?<=\n)calling` - look for the word "calling" if it immediately follows a newline.
2. `.*` Continue to non-greedily match anything
3. until you hit `(?=...|...|...)` one of (`|` means or):

   a. `\n[^\n]*completed succ[^\n]*\n` A line containing "completed succ". This is essentially a newline, as many non-newline characters as you want until "completed succ", more characters and finally a new line. The could probably end in the `completed succ` part, since I don't care about matching the rest of this line, now that I think about it.

   b. `\n\+\+` a newline starting with "++".

   c. `\s*\Z` Any amount of space characters (\n," ",\t etc.) until the end of the entire string `\Z`.

I would consider just using a loop, something like:

```
res = []
inside = False
with open('bla') as bla:
    for line in bla:
        if inside:
            if line.startswith('++') or "completed successfully" in line: 
                inside = False
            else:
                res[-1].append(line)              
        elif line.startswith("calling"):
            res.append([line])
            inside = True
```

Maybe error check that `inside==False` if the line starts with `calling`, just in case.

Comment: Tried it but not helping. It gives me only the lines where there are 2 continuous calling lines.

Comment: @ImdadulChoudhury I missed you want to match calls on the last line as well in your expected outputs - fixed. I'm nor sure by what you mean two continuous calls, but now the expected output matches what I have.

Comment: By continuous I meant the output is giving me the lines where there are 2 lines starting with "calling" together.

Comment: @ImdadulChoudhury I don't know what's wrong on your side, the output is what I pasted above using Python 3, and is exactly what you posted with the addition of `sequenc`, which I posted above. Both versions work.